# Angular 2.0 project no file named module.ts

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In the newer version of angular 2.0, when i create a angular project using angular CLI, there exists no file of module. Is it no more required or renamed ?

Comment: It should make a app.module.ts file in project-directory/src/app
What are the things you have there ?

Comment: In the root, there should be an app.module.ts as @IsuruAb mentioned. For the problem, What's the CLI version you're using?

Comment: its showing this way "angular-cli": "0.0.*",

Comment: @SaiyaffFarouk re-installing angular CLI solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome. Latest version of cli, the release candidate comes handy. @sara.bailwal